# Regex to slice filename contain string and numerical

Tags: php, regex, filenames

can anybody help me solve this :

i got

```
$filename= "index 198.php";
```

i use this and failed

```
preg_match(" [a-zA-Z0-9]", $filename, $output);
```

what kind of regex pattern i have to use so the **$output array** will be consist a **number only** value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract just the number from the file name you can do:

```
$filename= "index 198.php";
if(preg_match('#(\d+)#',$filename,$matches))
    echo $matches[1]; // prints 198
```

It assumes that the file name has just one group of digits. In case if there are more than one group of digits like `index 123 abc 456.php` only the first group will be matched.

Note:

The regex used is: `(\d+)`

- `\d` : short cut for `[0-9]`. A
  single digit
- `\d+` : one or more digits, basically
  a number
- `()` : to group and remember the match.
  It will be remembered in `$matches`
  arrray.
- `##` : delimiters. preg_ family of
  functions expect the 1st argument
  which is the regex to be inside a
  pair of delimiter. You could have
  used `'/(\d+)/'` too.

Answer (score 1):

a number only right??

```
$filename= "index 198.php";
preg_match_all("/(\d+)/",$filename,$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

to get more numbers, use preg_match_all()